# How to create a full page figure with flowing words in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word Document as such:

1. Heading 1
2. Subheading 1.1
3. Subheading 1.2
4. Heading 2
5. Heading 3

I want to place a full page image at the end of 2. However, there is a lot of white space now on the previous page.

So I would like 3/4/5 to fill that white space and automatically flow to the page after the full page figure, but I want the figure to always be locked as the nearest page after that heading.

How do I do that?